# How do spirits like Pret have sexual intercourse with humans at night?

Tags: shaivism, shaktism

Do they have similar bodies and body parts?

And does this sex cause some physical problem in the human "victim"?

How to tell if a spirit is having sex with you?

Comment: Voting to close the post as it is entirely non related to Hinduism.

Comment: Pret aatma & Bhoot are actually present in **Hindu scriptures**. They are also described in great detail in **Hindu scriptures**. They have many types and this is also given in **Hindu scriptures**. The physical problems they cause are also given in **Hindu scriptures**. Sex with humans is also given in **Hindu scriptures**.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar - curious, what makes you say it is not related to Hinduism ?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar it is related ro Hinduism imo.

Comment: Are you talking about tantric sadhnas? I have heard these type of things are very destructive to one's self and waste their precious human birth doing this type of sadhnas for personal material pleasure which later hurts the sadhak. For example read about Karna Pischachini Sadhna.

Comment: This question is broad. It contains multiple questions, please try to narrow down.

Answer (score 0):

Probably through their subtle body. This is the sexual practice of Pisachas:

> Manusmriti 3.34 - When the man has sex with a woman by stealth, while she is asleep, or drunk, intoxicated, or unconscious,—**it is the “Paiśāca” form**, the most sinful and evil of the ways of approaching women.